# Tried to boot Ubuntu, but the GRUB rescue prompt shows up instead

Tags: 12.04, grub2

Tried to boot Ubuntu, but this shows up instead:

```
grub rescue>
```

Comment: did you installed Ubuntu correctly? Have you ever booted your system after installation

Comment: Please indicate your [BootInfo URL](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11136267&postcount=1) to provide more information about your system.

Answer (score 34):

If you were able to boot Ubuntu in the past, but not now, follow these steps to solve the problem.

- First type `ls` command and Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see all the available partitions.
  The entries will be shown as `(hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos5)` etc.
- Then type `ls (hd0,msdos1)/` to see the content of the drive. if you see entries like  `vmliuz` or `initrd`, it is your Linux partition. If you fail with (hd0,msdos1), try with (hd0,msdos2) and so on, until you recognize your Ubuntu partition.
- When you correctly identify your Ubuntu partition, type `root=(hdX,msdosX)` , replace the `X` with correct identified number. For example, if you see `vmlinuz` and `initrd` entries by entering `ls (hd0,msdos5)`, the command will be `root=(hd0,msdos5)`.
- then type `configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will bring you Previous Ubuntu grub menu.
- Then choose the entry to boot Ubuntu.
- After you booted up, Open a terminal and type `sudo update-grub` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will update the grub menu and prevent future problems.

#### In the case that you are not able to boot to Ubuntu after installation, re-installing Ubuntu is the best option. You can check this question:

- [How to install Ubuntu OS Having already installed Windows OS](https://askubuntu.com/q/141108/61218)

Comment: No, I have never been able to boot. And this did not help. I've been having so many problems with Ubuntu...

Comment: Didn't work for me. After entering "configfile ..." it went back to the grub prompt, not the menu.

Comment: You can try `insmod normal`. See if work, since this answer is for Grub-Legacy

Comment: You are my hero

Answer (score 0):

I know this will sound irrelevant but after several restart attempts and before reading any posts, i decided to go to the bios in the scope of trying a restore defaults and / or change booting sequences.
The problem was solved just by pressing F2 several times, including at the very moment Grub was supposed to start.
I restarted a few times since then without any issues. 
My config is a dual booting with Ubuntu 12.04 & Windows 7

Hope it works for someone else

Answer (score 0):

Disconnecting my Windows 7 drive fixed this.

Comment: I doubt that is applicable, desirable, or even possible in most circumstances.

Comment: I tried the top answer, but did not see any files on the ubuntu drive. Also, it may be preferable to not change anything in the boot config if you can avoid it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster it is, if USB drive shows as hd0, then Ubuntu will not boot.

Comment: @MarkYisri: If you're still not using UUIDs or labels to `set root` in Grub (which is the default behaviour in Ubuntu since at least a few years), you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

For newer versions of ubuntu (16.04 ), this happens because ubuntu is trying to load in UEFI mode. But the usual install is Legacy mode, so go to BIOS->Boot Option->Select your Hard Disk and not UEFI Hard Disk.

Answer (score -1):

When this happened to me it was because I swaped out a drive that I made a line in fstab for it. Swaped the drive in and resolver the problem. Then added `error=continue`

Comment: the kernel won't even boot, how will this help the OP?

Answer (score -1):

If you still haven't got it to work, I would recommend (and this is the absolute LAST option) a full Ubuntu reinstall. If you have a flash drive with at least 3 Gigabytes of storage space, and you have the time and means to do so, reinstall Ubuntu using the following method:

Using your Windows drive, download Rufus from [here.](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Download your desired Ubuntu .iso file from [here.](https://www.ubuntu.com/download)

After the .iso file is downloaded, open Rufus and plug in your USB drive. Go to **Create a bootable disk using** and select **ISO Image**. Find and select the desired .iso image and click **Start**. The rest is as simple as waiting for it to install and booting from the drive.

Comment: what does this add to the other answer?

Comment: If it's not fixed, it provides a last resort.

Comment: the [other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/159850/595510) talks about reinstall too