# stuck on grub screen ubuntu13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, grub2

I tried installing ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 8 on my Asus K55V laptop (it came with windows 8 preinstalled) via USB, however whenever I try to boot ubuntu I just get to the command line prompt.

I've successfully installed 12.04 using the same method before, although a few applications didn't work (eg wine, steam and compizconfig), so I figured I'd try 13.04 instead.

I've tried this solution:
[Tried to boot Ubuntu, but the GRUB rescue prompt shows up instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-shows-up-instead)
but whenever i try running configfile it pauses for a second, clears the screen and asks for the next prompt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go into your BIOS settings by pressing `DEL` or `F2` or `F10`  after you power ON . A screen would come up with various options. Search for UEFI or Secure boot option across it,and disable it. Save and exit.

Follow instructions
[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)