# Lap wont boot after deleting windows7 partition

Tags: grub2

While I was using Ubuntu I accidently deleted the windows7 partition.  When I rebooted I got the following error:

```
error:unknown file system,Entering rescue mode,grub rescue>
```

I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu, windows7 but the windows set up is loading files after that the windows logo is blinking forever,on Ubuntu-install Ubuntu option selected but system freezes.

"ls" command is used in the grub rescue> it results

```
the hard disk partitions as(hd0) (hd0,msdos15)...(hd0,msdos5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mess things up too much, you can solve the problem by booting a liveDVD or liveUSB and use Boot-Repair by opening a terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I've tried that but the system hangs after selecting either 'try ubuntu'or 'install ubuntu'..is there any way to fix it without going inside the os,because the lap displaying only grub rescue screen nothing more

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/159850/27968

Comment: Unknown command 'configfile/boot/grub/grub.cfg'

Comment: Try [this](http://tuxers.com/main/instigating-a-manual-boot-from-the-grub-prompt/)

Comment: Unknown  command 'linux' .