# Ubuntu 17.10 boot problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bash, uefi

Just now installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my desktop (dual boot with windows 10). I got the `Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported` problem. I could not get to Ubuntu.
I tried to google for a solution and following are the methods I tried:

1. **Method 1:**
   I booted into a live session and installed boot-repair. Tried the recommended method as given in this link:
   https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/
   Tried this several times with no luck. It shows that the problem is solved, but when I reboot I get the same message.
2. **Method 2:**
   I followed the steps given in here: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) by logging into Ubuntu (following Method 3). Same problem.
3. **Method 3:** This is the only method through with I could log into Ubuntu. Got it from this source: [Tried to boot Ubuntu, but the GRUB rescue prompt shows up instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-prompt-shows-up-instead/849058). I can log into Ubuntu and repair grub. But after a reboot, I am back to the same problem. My Linux partition is at `(hd1,gpt11)`.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 17.10 3-4 times, so re-installing doesn't seem to be the solution. While installing I get the error `[    0:000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you installed both operating systems in uefi  mode ? What does the BIOS options for booting look like ? Secure boot ? Fast Boot ? UEFI/LEGACY ? 

Does windows boot ?

Comment: @vishnunarayanan Both OS are in UEFI boot mode, secure boot is off and I can boot into windows.

Answer (score 0):

I used `esc` key to get into grub en select a generic kernal to boot. the 'lowlatency' kernel selected by default does not work for me.

But maybe you do not even get into grub..